# react-dadata-suggestions не получается вытянуть value и поместить в onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Я делаю форму и использую для это useForm, и библиотеку react-dadata-suggestions: https://github.com/nobbynobbs/react-dadata-suggestions для того чтобы сделать поле email и через dadata подтягивать варианта email адреса. Для того чтобы осуществить работу react-dadata-suggestions и useForm я использую старый добрый контроллер, но у меня не получается передать в onChange value. Не знаю что делать.
Сам код:

```
<Controller 
  control={control} 
  name="email" 
  rules={{ 
    required: true
  }} 
  render={({ field: {onChange, onBlur, value} }) => (
    <> 
      <DadataSuggestions 
        token="token" 
        onSelect={ (suggestion) => console.log(suggestion) } 
        service="email" 
        count={5} 
        onChange={ (event) => onChange(event.target.value) } // строка, в которой по моему мнению проблема
       /> 
    </> 
  } 
/>
```

React выводит вот такую вот ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверь,что возвращает DadataSuggestions внутри onChange. Ошибка говорит о том, что event.target не определен и соответственно невозможно прочитать у него параметр value. А там уже будет видно какой параметр тебе нужно вытаскивать и передавать в свой onChange